# How can i resolve this poblem on flutter

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have this issue in flutter, this is my codes,
And the when i try to use jsonData in the widget it's empty but i attribute it a data in initstate, and print show all the data.
A solution for this gyus i'm out of solution, i've tried to call the loadJson an buildWidget but nothing, NB: I'm beginner in coding

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables

import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'package:ezango/pages/authenticate.dart';
import 'package:ezango/pages/homescreen.dart';
import 'package:ezango/pages/offer.dart';
import 'package:ezango/services/database.service.dart';
import 'package:ezango/services/supabase.credentials.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  double progress = 0.0;
  String userMail = '';
  final userData = GetStorage();
  DateTime? retrievedDateTime;
  late var connectivityResult;
  late Future<void> initialization;
  bool isLoading = false;
  List<dynamic> jsonData = [];
  int counter = 0;
  List<dynamic> newData = [];
  late SharedPreferences prefs;
  late bool isLoggedIn;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
    isLoggedIn = userData.read("isLogged") ?? false;
    initialization = getUserDateExpiredAndConnectionStatus();
  }

  Future<void> getData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    counter = prefs.getInt('verbe') ?? 0;
    print(counter);
    loadJsonData();
  }

  Future<void> loadJsonData() async {
    try {
      String jsonContent = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/verbe.json');
      jsonData = json.decode(jsonContent);
      counter = counter.clamp(0, jsonData.length - 1);
      // Take the first 'counter' elements from jsonData
      newData = jsonData.take(counter).toList();
      // Reverse the newData
      print("jsonData: $jsonData");
    } catch (error) {
      print('Error loading JSON data: $error');
    }
  }

  Future<void> getUserDateExpiredAndConnectionStatus() async {
    DataBaseService().fetchAllContes();
    DataBaseService().fetchAllBook();
    DataBaseService().fetchAllStory();
    connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    SharedPreferences prefHere = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    SharedPreferences prefIsPaidUser = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    try {
      userMail = await userData.read("email");
      final response = await SupabaseCredentials.supabaseClient
          .from("users")
          .select()
          .eq('email', userMail);
      List dataList = response as List;
      String expirationDate = dataList[0]["expirationDate"];
      retrievedDateTime = DateTime.parse(expirationDate);
      bool isPV = dataList[0]["isPremiumVIP"];
      bool isPaidUser = dataList[0]["isPaidUser"];
      await prefHere.setBool("isVP", isPV);
      await prefIsPaidUser.setBool("isPaidUser", isPaidUser);
      print("isVP : $isPV isPaidUser: $isPaidUser dt: $expirationDate");
    } catch (e) {
      userMail = "";
      print("Error : $e");
    }
  }

  Future<void> startProgress(String letter) async {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 5));
      setState(() {
        progress = i.toDouble();
      });
      print(jsonData[1]["Verbe"]);
    }

    // Wait for 5 seconds before navigating to the next page
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 20));
    if (letter == "a") {
      Get.offAll(() => const Offer());
    } else if (letter == "b") {
      Get.offAll(() => const HomeScreen());
    } else {
      Get.offAll(() => const AutheticationPage());
    }
    // Navigate to the next page
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double deviceWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final double deviceHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    int count = counter > 3 ? 3 : counter + 1;
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: initialization,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: InkWell(
                onTap: () async {
                  if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
                    Get.defaultDialog(
                      title: "Pas de connexion, l'accés internet est requis",
                      middleText:
                          "Veuillez activer votre connexion et rouvrir l'application ",
                    );
                  } else {
                    if (isLoggedIn) {
                      if (retrievedDateTime!.isBefore(DateTime.now())) {
                        String resp = await updateUser(userMail);
                        if (resp == "succes") {
                          Get.defaultDialog(
                              title: "Réveillez l'Okambi\n qui est en vous",
                              titleStyle: const TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
                              textConfirm: "Ok",
                              middleText:
                                  "Votre abonnement ou votre essai gratuit est fini, veuillez acheter une nouvelle offre",
                              onConfirm: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  isLoading = true;
                                });
                                startProgress("a");
                              });
                        } else {}
                      } else {
                        setState(() {
                          isLoading = true;
                        });
                        startProgress("b");
                      }
                    } else {
                      setState(() {
                        isLoading = true;
                      });
                      startProgress("c");
                    }
                  }
                },
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  width: deviceWidth,
                  height: deviceHeight,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage('assets/background_casque.png'),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage("assets/log.png"))),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: deviceWidth,
                        height: deviceHeight * 0.4,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white54,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    vertical: 10, horizontal: 25),
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.white54,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                                child: text(
                                    'Le Saviez-vous ?', 20, FontWeight.bold)),
                            text('Verbe:', 15, FontWeight.normal),
                            jsonData.isEmpty
                                ? text('Go ${jsonData[1 + counter]["Verbe"]}',
                                    20, FontWeight.bold)
                                : Container(
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                    height: 20,
                                  ),
                            text('Définition:', 15, FontWeight.normal),
                            jsonData.isEmpty
                                ? text('${jsonData[1 + counter]["Définition"]}',
                                    20, FontWeight.bold)
                                : Container(
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                    height: 20,
                                  ),
                            text('Exemple:', 15, FontWeight.normal),
                            jsonData.isEmpty
                                ? text('${jsonData[1 + counter]["Exemple"]}',
                                    20, FontWeight.bold)
                                : Container(
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                    height: 20,
                                  ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 20),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      isLoading
                          ? const CircularProgressIndicator(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            )
                          : const Text(
                              'Appuyez pour commencer',
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return const Scaffold(
              body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            );
          }
        });
  }
}

Widget text(String text, double fontSize, FontWeight fontweight) {
  return Text(
    text,
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white, fontSize: fontSize, fontWeight: fontweight),
  );
}

Future<String> updateUser(String userMail) async {
  try {
    var response = await SupabaseCredentials.supabaseClient
        .from("users")
        .update({"isPremiumVIP": false, "isPaidUser": false}).eq(
            "email", userMail);
    return "succes";
  } catch (e) {
    return "error";
  }
}
```